# How to use an image-map in a swfObject

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flash, swfobject

I am having trouble getting an image map to work for a SWF file.
According to the flex 4 documentation I can use an image-map for a swfobject(if flash player v10+):
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/UsingSDK/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f18.html

I made a basic example, but could not get the image-map to work.

HTML:

```
<div id="replace"></div>
<map name="maptest">
    <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,275,200" href="http://www.google.com/" target="_blank" />
</map>
```

JS:

```
var params = {
"usemap": "#maptest"
};
swfobject.embedSWF("http://philipp.werminghausen.us/testing/test.swf", 'replace', 275, 200, "11", null, {}, params, {}, function (res) {});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/me2loveit2/Uth59/

an I missing something?

Comment: The swfobject call looks fine.  Do you have a working image-map without a swf involved?

Comment: Image maps on images are working fine for me. Check out the fiddle I updated it: http://jsfiddle.net/me2loveit2/Uth59/1/